# Enforcing generic interface as the value of an annotation in Java

Tags: java, generics, annotations

Are there ways to receive a generic type as a value in Java annotations?

```java
// The generics interface:
public interface TypeConverter<S, R> {
    public R convert(S sourceType); 
}

// The implementation:
public DateConverter extends TypeConverter<String, Date> {
    public String convert(Date sourceType) { ... }
}

// Applying the custom converter through an annotation on a field:
...
Converter(DateConverter.class);
public Date dateField;
...

// The issue! Receiving the generic type in an annotation value:
public @interface Converter {
    //How to use the generic type as the type of "value"?
    Class value() default void.class;
    // versus
    //Class<? extends TypeConverter> type() default void.class;
}
```

Check the comments out on the annotation `Converter` above.

Comment: In a word, no..

Comment: @AndyTurner Are there any workaround?

Comment: I'm not actually clear what role the annotation would be intended to play here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this, however, there is one workaround that you might be interested in.

If you don't want your annotation parameter to be required and you cannot pass the default value, you can always use arrays instead.

```
public @interface Converter {
  Class<? extends TypeConverter>[] type() default {};
}
//.. and the possible usages
@Converter
@Converter(type = FooConverter.class)
@Converter(type = { FooConverter.class, ThisIsWhatCanHappen.class }) // this is the downside of this approach

// retrieving type from annotation
void foo(Converter converter) {
  TypeConverter typeConverter = converter.type().length > 0
    ? converter.type()[0]
    : null; // or some default value
  // now that you have your TypeConverter do a backflip or something
}
```

There are two downsides

- An array can be any length, you have no control over it (which can be confusing)
- It is slightly less comfortable to use, you have to check if an array is not empty and get it's first element to access the `type` value.